# How to redirect more than 10000+ URLs

Tags: azure, redirect, http-redirect, azure-front-door

Currently, our website is hosted on the SAP cloud and we have a lot of redirects that are handled by SAP. We just upload the files which contain the URL redirects and SAP internally takes care of the redirect. More details can be found here - https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/0fa6bcf4736c46f78c248512391eb467/d88300faa78f4acfabb5f4d344070778.html?version=v2011

We are moving the website from SAP to Azure and I know we can handle URL redirects in Azure Frontdoor but I don't think Azure Frontdoor can 10000+ redirects. Is there an alternative to Azure Frontdoor which can handle such huge redirects or is there any other tool outside Azure that can handle such huge redirects?

Answer (score 0):

Simulated the new front door application with SAP routing rules
Step1:
Creating new front door classic application
[image]

Step2:
Under the Routing Rule, we can add multiple routing configuration on Front door
[image]

[image]

example for multiple route configurations:
[image]

refer this  [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-rules-engine-actions?pivots=front-door-standard-premium&tabs=portal)  for more information